# Redirect apache to tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, ip, tomcat7

I am trying to redirect domain.com to tomcat7, I tried a lot of configurations and doesnt seem to work...

This is my /etc/tomcat7/server.xml config

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"
            proxyName="domain.com"
            proxyPort="80"
            />
```

And this is my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
AddModule mod_proxy.c

ProxyPass / http://domain.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.com:8080/

<Location "/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

When i go to domain.com i get this default apache message:

```
It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

When i go to domain.com:8080 i get the tomcat message:

```
It works !
If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully.     Congratulations!
This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at:     /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html
```

I loaded few .WAR with tomcat assistant one is called App1.
If i go to domain.com/App1 i get:

```
The requested URL /App1/ was not found on this server.
```

But if i use domain.com:8080/App1 the app works properly and shows a for loop for example.

UPDATE: tried /etc/apache2/ports.conf with this config:

```
Listen 80
ServerName domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
NameVirtualHost IP
```

UPDATE2: i just wiped out my debian and i just used /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to set this: (only with this file I achieved same result as above, still must use domain.com:8080/appname to run an app...)

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I do it to redirect straight to tomcat default message instead of apaches ?
And how to get rid of that :8080 and make apps work on domain.com/appname

Comment: Is the `ProxyPass`, etc. defined in a `VirtualHost`? If so, is that `VirtualHost` the one handling the requests to `http://domain.com/`? Once you get httpd->Tomcat working, you won't have to worry about the `:8080` (that's the point of the question, right?).

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz is it the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file?

Comment: Only you can tell me how your Apache httpd is configured. Try searching for `<VirtualHost>` and seeing if your ProxyPass is within whatever VirtualHost applies.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no success, tried this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts and then this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html still not working, pfff... updating post with ports.conf

Comment: Your `ProxyPass` line should work as writte. I'm just trying to figure out if that configuration just isn't active for the request you are trying to make. Try commenting-out the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directive and change the `<Location>` to `Deny from all`, reload the configuration and see if you can successfully lock everyone out of everything. That will tell you if your configuration is actually being used.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz pfff it still works, so damn tired of this lol. I dont have any important information, I can make a clean OS (debian7) install... But what should I do after a fresh start, could you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64412/discussion-between-alpha2k-and-christopher-schultz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long time this is tha answer:

```
    Edit file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

using `!` to prevent forwarding phpadmin to tomcat